# Transfer Wordpress site to another domain

Tags: themes, server, migration

I'm working on a website now and then I want to transfer to other domain.
But all I want to transfer is the WordPress Theme and content not included the plugins

Is this possible?
If yes how?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a big fan of using Duplicator

https://en-gb.wordpress.org/plugins/duplicator/

I would move the whole site and then delete the plugins once moved.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to manually do all site transfer things it's not a hard work.

Also you can use [WP CLone](https://ru.wordpress.org/plugins/wp-clone-by-wp-academy/) or [All-in-one-wp-migration](https://wordpress.org/plugins/all-in-one-wp-migration/) which provide a great tools for migration.